# How to extract the word Default from this xml?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, appium, nokogiri

```xml
<XCUIElementTypeCell type="XCUIElementTypeCell" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="165" width="320" height="40">
    <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="165" width="320" height="1">
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="165" width="320" height="40">
      <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="165" width="320" height="40">
      </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" enabled="true" visible="true" x="16" y="165" width="258" height="40" name="Default" label="Default" value="Default">
    </XCUIElementTypeStaticText>
    <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" enabled="true" visible="true" x="16" y="203" width="304" height="2">
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeButton type="XCUIElementTypeButton" enabled="false" visible="true" x="284" y="176" width="18" height="17" name="checkmark" label="checkmark">
    </XCUIElementTypeButton>
  </XCUIElementTypeCell>
```

After a lot of searching, from a bigger xml I managed to extract this smaller bit using this code:

```
  xml = $D[device].page_source
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
  res = doc.xpath('//*[@name="checkmark"]').first.parent
```

My goal is to find out what word is preceding the checkmark. I can see in xml that it is the word `Default` but I am not able to establish this in code. I use Ruby.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XPath expression to select the last element that has the attribute "name" just before the element with attribute "name"="checkmark"

```
//*[@name="checkmark"][1]/preceding::*[@name][1]
```

You can try it [here](http://xpather.com/Taq3zqO5)

What is does is, selects the first element with name=checkmark (just to avoid cases where there are more than one), and then selects its preceding nodes that have name and gets the first (preceding list goes in reverse order)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Exhile79. Your code gave me the node, out of which I am getting the word "Default" or "Custom". My code is like this:

```
element_selected = doc.xpath('//*[@name="checkmark"][1]/preceding::*[@name][1]')

if element_selected.attr("value").to_s == "Custom"
  $custom_greeting_activated = true
else
  $custom_greeting_activated = false
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Did my answer solved your problem or not? If yes, please accept it as the correct answer. If no, what else do you need?